# Firefox shuts down with silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have two silverlight applications on the same page that use the same methods from the same classes on page load.

This causes issues in firefox (*firefox doesn't respond and shuts down/crashes*), but it is okay in IE and chrome.

*Is there a reason for this?*

Comment: Could you isolate what function in particular is crashing firefox? Is there anything that uses the HTML Bridge to access something outside the Silverlight application?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not actually sure if it's the function that's crashing. Do you know if Firefox calls the asp.net framework in any different way than the other browsers do?